# Importing csv into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I've got a csv file I made with a bunch of info, but I cant get it to import properly...

Ive got these values in info.csv: id    firstname   lastname    address state   gpa credits

following a video, I used this:

```html
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/IT101/info.csv' INTO TABLE 'student' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get back:

```html
PAGER set to stdout
```

and the values aren't there. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: By the way, I alaready have two rows in the table from using insert into, just doing it 30 more times seemed like a waste of time

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Comment: @MisterDood Server version says  5.5.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try...

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/IT101/info.csv' 
INTO TABLE students 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```